# Android dispatchTouchEvent, onTouchEvent, onTouch stop working after 1-5 minutes

Tags: android, touch, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I develop OpenGL ES 2.0 (`GLSurfaceView`) android game. Touch events stop working after sometime 1-5 minutes. I do not add any subviews. I have ad networks integrated but internet is turned off.

First I implemented `onTouch` method from `OnTouchListener` interface. Then I implemented `onTouchEvent` in `GLSurfaceView` and later `dispatchTouchEvent`

All these method get called for the first few minutes but stop get called. It is not related to game play.

What may course these issues?

I wrapped code in `onTouch` with try/catch block and put breakpoint in catch to ensure there is no exception in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lock the UI thread then it will block touch but will not block GL thread. It will also block `runOnUiThread` calls.

Comment: Yes. It was `ArrayBlockingQueue` set to 10. When internet was not available it was blocking when messages from not sent by background thread. With good internet connection it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is something intercepting, and consuming the touch event that is "above" your surface view.  I wonder if your ad network is perhaps displaying some sort of invisible ad? (invisible because there is no network?).  Do you see the problem when you remove the ad network?

Comment: I removed nothing changes.